# Search display controller prevent hiding the cancel button if the search text field is empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have search display controller and I want the cancel button to be always visible , I set the option of "**shows the cancel button**" from the interface builder "**xib** file" and I handled the delegate of

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
{
    controller.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```

to make the cancel button always shown , it works correct if the search text input has text , but if I did not enter any text in the search bar and click on the faded view the search textfield stop editing this is correct behavior but it hides the cancel button so how i can make the cancel button  always shown ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate=self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate=self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.delegate=self;
```

and in begin search

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
{
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: it has the same problem , Ok how I can handle the click on the faded view

Comment: faded view of search displaycontroller?

Comment: have u enabled the display controller?

Comment: what you mean by enabled it ?